# Replace "Step x) Get value" to "Step x. Get value" using python 3, Where x is an integerr value

Tags: python, replace

```
s="Step 1)Get value"
s1=s.replace("Step \(.*)\)", "")
print(s1)
```

Output getting: `Step 1)Get value`

Required Output: `Step 1.Get value`

Where 1 can be any integer

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use a regex but string doesnt support that it will assumed you literally mean (.*)" which since you dont have that in your stirng there is nothing to replace. If you want to substitute using regex then look at re.sub in the re module

Comment: But is your code as simple as you want to replace `)` for `.` cause if so then just do `s1 = s.replace(")", ".")`

Answer (score 0):

by using python regex you can replace a specific position by substitution.....

```
import re

s="Step 1)Get value"
pat=re.sub("\)",".",s)#instead of ')' you can replace '.'
print(pat)
```

the pattern will be.....

```
Step 1.Get value
```

hope it is helpful.....

Answer (score 0):

For example
s="Step 1)Get value(100000)"
I dont want replace all brace 
I want to replace Step 1.
Where 1 can be any integer